# Puxar imagens no HTML com Node Js + Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, imagem, express.js

Galera estou começando com o nodejs e tenho uma duvida. Sempre que chamo ima imagem ou até mesmo o bootstrap no meu arquivo eu tenho que usar o sendfile. Sempre que u por um icone ou imagem eu terei que setar a rota no node e depois no arquivo, ou existe uma forma mais prática para isto?

Comment: Se você mapear a pasta public no express e adicionar sua imagem nesta pasta, tu acessa ela a parti do html sem precisar enviar.

Comment: Envia por favor como está sua linha de código pra mostrar esse ícone e/ou imagem, quando quero carregar alguma imagem eu só faço desta forma: <img src="/public/img/imagem.jpg" />